# '80s movie with a humanoid alien in a glass casket

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I've been trying to find this movie for a long time now. I watched it as a kid, so my memories are quite vague.

The most impressive thing I remember was some kind of a humanoid alien in a glass casket, with a stone on its forehead which was blinking to indicate it's alive or waking up. There was some kind of expedition that found it in a cave. I think they entered the cave from above and there were hundreds of snakes covering the floor. Unfortunately I don't recall anything about the plot itself.

I believe the movie should be from '80s, or somewhere around that period.

P.S. I talked to my brother who watched it with me. He was even younger at that time, but managed to recall that the expedition found some kind of substance in the cave that made them evil when they touched it and the same stone appeared on their forehead as well. The final scene of the movie was in an airplane - the pilot turns around and people see he also has been "infected" and has that gem on his face.

Comment: Snakes? Why did it have to be snakes?

Comment: Might it be an old Doctor Who story? I don't remember that one, exactly, but there were hundreds of them, all very low-budget, and this seems similar to many of the plots I have seen.

Comment: Thanks! As far as I know Doctor Who is a TV Series and I am certain I watched this film in a movie theater. Thanks a lot for the idea, but it's not the one.

Comment: @Entity - Can you clarify whether you saw this film in the early '80s, mid '80s or late '80s? If you're struggling to recall, it might help to try and think of any famous films you know you'd already seen at the time, like _ET: The Extra Terrestrial_ or _Back to the Future_.

Comment: @LogicDictates It should have been for sure late 80s or early 90s, however I live in Bulgaria and it was a time when we had little access to foreign movies and quite a bit of them were non US ones. Mostly Chinese and Japanese ones so the movie might not be even from US. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the guys who gave suggestions and tried to help me find the movie!
I'm really grateful for the hints! My brother was searching for that movie for years as well and I never knew that. Luckily when we combined our memories we managed to find it almost by accident. He came across [this article](http://www.whatthefestnyc.com/film/curse-of-snakes-valley/) and solved the mystery.

The movie is called ***[Curse of Snakes Valley](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0095456/?ref_=ttmi_tt)* (1988)**

And here is the alien in the casket which scared the shit out of me when I watched it as a kid.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this is probably *[Time Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Walker)* (1982).

[image]

A casket containing a mummified alien is discovered within King Tut's tomb. The casket is taken to the California Institute of the Sciences, where the alien subsequently wakes up with a glowing orb in its chest. That particular scene occurs about 15 minutes into the video below.

It's not a perfect match for your description, admittedly. There don't appear to be any snakes in the film, the casket isn't made of glass or transparent, and the glowing orb is in the chest rather than the head. But you said you were a kid when you saw it, so you could've misremembered a few things.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! 

Time Walker does seem to have similarities to the movie I'm searching for but I'm very certain there were snakes in the cave where they found the alien and it wasn't mummified although it did appear to be dead or sleeping. 

I took a look at the link but I don't think it's the one I'm looking for.